# How can I center a WebGL window in Unity?

Tags: unity, webgl

I have a WebGL build for my game, however, I'm getting frequent requests to center the image. Right now it is left justified. How can I center the WebGL game window?

[image]

Comment: You won't get good answers without a more specific question. Center what window, in what? What is your picture representing? All I see is a glowy blue box with scrollbars and a different black box. And, most importantly, what have you already tried, and why doesn't it work?

Comment: The picture is a screenshot of my web browser when loading my build. The game window should be centered in my browser, not off to the left. I've looked at the CSS file, but I can't figure out what if anything I could tweak to have the desired effect. I've also looked at the player settings.

Comment: Have you tried changing the game resolution from the editor?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom WebGLTemplate just [change the HTML as documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html). You can choose either one of the defaults or create your own template.

According to those docs you create folder in `Assets` called `WebGLTemplates` and inside that create a new folder for your template like `BetterTemplate`. Inside that put an `index.html` file and any other images, css, JavaScript files you want included with your game.

The index.html could look something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>%UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      #gameContainer { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
      canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>
    <script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
    var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/dist.json");
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="gameContainer"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Then you pick Edit->Project Settings->Player from the menus and under the WebGL tab choose your template

[image]

[Here's an example that provides a custom logo](https://github.com/greggman/better-unity-webgl-template).